# Calculate percentage in InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a table in InfluxDB, I just need to calculate error percentage by

```
SELECT count(threadName) FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE "runId" ='80' as totalcount 

SELECT count(threadName) FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE "runId" ='80'and errorCount=1 as error

now need to calculate error/totalcount*100.
```

using influxdb query /by graffana . How can achieve it ? is there any way i can use scripting?

Comment: What is you current InfluxDB query

Comment: @tomgalpin  SELECT count(threadName) FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE "runId" ='80'  is the query for Total Count and SELECT count(threadName) FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE "runId" ='80' and errorCount!=0 is the query for error count.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, this works for me:

```
SELECT (mean("error") / mean("totalcount") * 100) FROM (SELECT count(threadName) FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE "runId" ='80' as totalcount ),(SELECT count(threadName) FROM "requestsRaw" WHERE "runId" ='80'and errorCount=1 as error)
```

Also you can try to use Grafana Expression feature to do 2 queries and separate math in Expression